# python -- is there a way to access a function which is in the init method in a class?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class random_walk:
    #ns: number of steps
    #np: number of particles
    #dimension : choose between 1D or 2D
    def __init__(self,ns,np,dimension=None):
        self.ns=ns
        self.np=np
        self.dimension=dimension

        if  self.dimension==2:
            #--- These represent the orientation of movement ------------
            step=random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]])
            def step2d(self,ns):
                return [step for i in range(ns)]

    #steps=table with trajectories that constitute from m steps
    def steps(self,ns):    
        return 2*sc.random.random_integers(0,1,size=self.ns)-1
```

If I do `rw=random_walk(ns,np)` and then `rw.steps(ns)` it works ok.

But if I try `rw=random_walk(ns,np,dimension)` and then `rw.step2d(ns)` it gives me: `random_walk instance has no attribute 'step2d'`.

As far as I understand, it is because the `step2d` function is in the init method. Is there a way to access it?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it's local to the `__init__` method. If you want to call it from the outside, you have to declare it as such (i.e. make it a method of the class/instances of the class).

Comment: Why is in there in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to actually put the `step2d()` method on the class, not in the `__init__()` method. Python *does* let you add a method to your instance dynamically, so you could define it in `__init__()` like you have and then add it to the instance if the dimensionality is 2, but it is kind of hairy since you also need to create a bound method wrapper for it or it won't work right. It is also a bad design and will be confusing to other programers who look at your code. So don't do it that way.

Instead, either:

1. Have a distinct subclass for 2D objects that has the `step2d()` method. You can have a factory function that returns an instance of the proper class depending on the dimensionality (or implement the factory as part of the base class's `__new__()`).
2. Simply define `step2d()` as another method; check `self.dimension` right at the top and raise `TypeError` if dimensionality is not 2. Like so:

   ```
   def step2d(self, ns):
       if self.dimension != 2:
           raise TypeError("dimension must be 2")
       # continue with what to do if the dimensionality is 2
   ```

Comment: Thanks!I did the (2).I tested it but it doesn't raise an exception if for example dimension=3.I did:if  self.dimension==2:
            try:
                return [random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]]) for i in range(ns)]  
            except TypeError:
                print("The dimensions must be 2")

Comment: Now,it works,thanks.But i can't understand why it didn't work before.

Comment: You were using a try/except and catching the `TypeError` rather than raising the error yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do; change the class signiture based on arguments passed to an instance method, doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

What you should probably do is define two classes:

```
class random_walk:
    #ns: number of steps
    #np: number of particles
    #dimension : choose between 1D or 2D
    def __init__(self,ns,np,dimension=None):
        self.ns=ns
        self.np=np
        self.dimension=dimension

    #steps=table with trajectories that constitute from m steps
    def steps(self,ns):    
        return 2*sc.random.random_integers(0,1,size=self.ns)-1

class random_walk_2d(random_walk):

    def step2d(self,ns):
        return [step for i in range(ns)]
```

And then define a factory function that returns the correct class:

```
def make_random_walk(ns, np, dimensions=None):
    if dimensions ==  2:
        return random_walk_2d(ns, np, 2)
    else:
        return random_walk(ns, np, dimensions)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.I didn't chose it because i found below one which was closer to what i was thinking.But i think i will use your approach some time.

Answer (score 0):

No it’s not possible to access it outside of the `__init__` method. You are declaring it in the scope of that method, so it is bound to that scope. If you want to access it on the outside, you have to declare it somewhere else, for example as a (private) method of the class.

Btw. your random walk won’t work the way you expect it. You are executing `random.choice` a single time and then you build a list of length `ns` with that single calculated value. So you end up with the same direction for all the steps. You have to move the `choice` call inside of the loop, so each step is randomized. You could utilize a generator then btw.:

```
def step2d ( self, ns ):
    for i in range( ns ):
        yield random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]])
```